# R package 'TranslateR' does not show the translated results

Tags: r, nlp, google-translate

I was using the R package "translateR" with google translation API key, with the default dataset 'enron' like following:

> data(enron) is a data frame with 10 observations on the following 3 variables.
>   email A character vector of the email’s body.
>   date The email’s timestamp as a ’Date’ type.
>   subject A character vector containing the email’s subject line

#### The code

```
library(translateR) # Loading the package
data(enron) # Loading the dataset to be translated
tc <- translate(dataset = enron, 
                content.field = 'email', 
                google.api.key = 'my google.api.key', 
                source.lang = 'en', 
                target.lang = 'de')
print(tc)
```

#### Expected

dataset 'tc' is supposed to be the orginal dataset with an addtional column "translatedContent" appended.

#### Result

dataset 'tc' is the same as the input dataset 'enron', no translated contents can be seen.

#### Addition information

My google translation API key works well, its working for the other r package 'translate'.

I am using RStudio Version 1.1.383 with the latest R version 3.4.2
on OS X 10.10.5

Comment: What's your output? Do you get an error message? Have you tried calling the function explicitly? i.e. `translateR::translate()`, I found function `translate()` in other packages so there could be a conflict when calling it.

Comment: @epo3 My output is the same as the input. I don't get an error message. Calling the `translate()` function with `translateR::translate()` gives the same results.